# tags with unicode in names, and lxml

Tags: python, unicode, lxml

Assume I have a document which uses Unicode in tag names, as for example `<año>2012</año>`.

When I use etree from lxml to parse such a document, I have no problems, the tree is correctly built. But when (for debugging purposes) I try to print some elements, I get an exception about a failed attempt to encode as ASCII some unicode char.

Is not a problem of terminal configuration or bad encoding of the file, since I can print without problem the name of the node (`.tag`), which contains the same unicode char. Apparently the problem is caused by the "stringification" of the Element object, which assumes that the tag names are aways plain ascii.

The following code shows the problem (and also shows that it is not a file/terminal/encoding problem).

```
# coding: utf-8
from lxml import etree
doc = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<año>2012</año>
"""
x = etree.fromstring(doc)   # No problem
print x.tag                 # No problem
print x                     # Exception
```

Running the above script in a terminal with a properly defined LC_CTYPE, produces the following output:

```
año
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "procesar.py", line 8, in <module>
    print x
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Note how `print x.tag` outputs correctly `año`. Shouldn't `print x` produce something like `<Element año at b7d26eb4>`?

Is this a known problem? Any ideas about workarounds?

Comment: I can reproduce this with lxml. ElementTree works; it prints `<Element u'a\xf1o' at 0xbf5530>`.

Comment: I tried using ElementTree and have the same exception. Perhaps I'm using an older version and the problem was fixed. help(elementtree) shows `# $Id: __init__.py 1821 2004-06-03 16:57:49Z fredrik $` in my machine, which looks old enough...

Btw, when you said "I can reproduce this..." do you mean you have the same problem, or there is a typo?

Comment: Anyway... and this is a somewhat different question. How can I redefine Element.__repr__ so I can try fixing the problem? If I try to do `x.__repr__ = other_function` I get `AttributeError: 'etree._Element' object attribute '__repr__' is read-only`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to transform unicode strings into byte strings before output

Try:

```
print unicode(x).encode('utf8')
```

quoting the [unicode function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unicode):

> For objects which provide a __unicode__() method, it will call this method without arguments to create a Unicode string. For all other objects, the 8-bit string version or representation is requested and then converted to a Unicode string using the codec for the default encoding in 'strict' mode.

Comment: In fact, the final encode step is not required, because python automatically tries to encode unicode strings to the terminal encoding. In my case, since I defined `LC_ALL`, `print unicode(x)` works. However, I cannot understand why. I pressume that unicode(x) tries first x.__str__ or x.__repr__ which should raise the same exception, shouldn't?

Comment: @JLDiaz Python tries to use the `__unicode__` method first, if it doesn't exist, a conversion is tried. Added a quote about this in the answer.

Comment: @Marcin No, he is using an object like a string, you can't simply "print" an object, it makes no sense, it has to be converted, and that's what unicode function does, convert it to an unicode string.

Comment: @KurzedMetal However, print x.__unicode__() doesn't work, since Element object does not provide a __unicode__() method. So... how can it work?

Comment: @KurzedMetal Your code is correct, but your explication is misleading at best.

Comment: @JLDiaz That's why you are supposed to use `unicode()` and not call `__unicode__()` directly, `__unicode__` is there only to be overriden at class implementation.